# How to read sitemap url text from robots.txt file

Tags: c#, asp.net, if-statement, robots.txt, sitemap.xml

I want to read the text of robots.txt file(www.abcd.com/robots.txt) which contains the sitemap url from my C# application. I have to use if else to generate Alerts if sitemap url present in robots.txt file then it displays yes and it does not contain sitemap url then it will display no.

Robots.txt file text look like this:

```
# Crawlers Setup
User-agent: *
Disallow:
Crawl-delay: 10

# Website Sitemap
Sitemap: http://www.abcd.com/sitemap.xml
```

How can I read this sitemap text from robots.txt file as robots.txt is also a link not actually a text file. It is www.abcd.com/robots.txt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a library like [RobotsTxt](https://bitbucket.org/cagdas/robotstxt) (disclaimer: project owner here). Example:

```
string contentsOfRobotsTxtFile = new WebClient().DownloadString("uri");
Robots robots = Robots.Load(content);
var sitemaps = robots.Sitemaps;
```

It's available on Nuget as well ; http://www.nuget.org/packages/RobotsTxt/

Comment: is it possible to get only the disallowed rules?

Answer (score -1):

You just read the file, like this:

```
string contentOfRobotTxt= new WebClient().DownloadString("http://www.abcd.com/robots.txt");
```

Comment: The Robot.txt will be loaded into the String object contentOfRobotTxt. You will need to process this with a simple string search